# How to show like count

Tags: python, html, django

**models.py**

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')
```

**views.py**

```py
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, "network/index.html", {'posts': posts})
```

**network/index.html**

```html
<h1>All Post</h1>
<ul>
  {% for post in posts %}
  <li>
    <div>{{ post.content }}</div>
    <div>{{post.likes}}</div>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

which results following output
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU5Gy.png)

How to count `like` for each `Post`?
I know that by running

```py
post = Post.objects.get(pk=<your_postid>).likes.all().count()
```

gives all like count, but how can I loop over it.

Comment: Do you want to count the likes or loop over them?

Comment: @KlausD. If you have seen `index.html` image then what i'm trying to achieve is, to show like `objects` count for each post `object` Q: count the likes? (yes)

Answer (score 0):

> network/index.html

```html
<h1>All Post</h1>
<ul>
  {% for post in posts %}
  <li>
    <div>{{ post.content }}</div>
    <div>{{post.likes.count}}</div>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```